# UWP and EF Compiler Warnings

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

To start learning UWP wit EFCore, I followed thislink
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sql-server-databases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QD6z.png)

The table shows OK, but I have 114 warnings when compiling the project, not sure what I did wrong or how to fix it... 
I'm running VS 2017 on a Windows 10 x64 machine
Also the last warning (NU1603) is also weird to me
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hover over the error icon and see the error message, what does it say?

Comment: I updated the post with a new image, the the last warning (NU1603) is also weird to me.

Comment: The last warning wouldn't be a big concern now .. However, what does the error icon say ?(put your mouse over the yellow triangle)

Comment: I'm trying but nothing shows up... The windows description says that the reference could not be found (check the image that posted), mouse over the yellow icon only say warning